# Jquery Image Animation from one location to another

Tags: jquery

I want to do a simple image animation.Assume that there is small image of 100*100 pixel image at location A. I want to move the image from location A to location B and maximize the at location B.

I have both the dimension images small and large. I don't want to increase the width and height of image itself. I have a separate image for showing large one.

I have seen this kind of effect in flash , flex. If user clicks on image A it maintains the transition so that user doesn't loose the context.

I will have 20 images in a grid and a left panel to hold the big image. Whenever you click any image on the grid , it gets refresh the left panel with all the details about that image.Right now i am just replace the left panel with big image. can you please give me any directions how to achieve this transition

Comment: This is not a question, it's a request for people to write your code for you. Please show us you tried something before coming here or this question will be closed

Comment: some kind of direction is enough. I tried jquery animation effects but they didn't come good in time. I am not expecting code at all , any inputs or some related links enough for me to start.

Comment: In the future, please specify what you already tried to prevent people from wasting their time and making mods suspicious

Comment: @Eran , will do that. We have implemented some functionality on http://www.art.com/gallery/id--c23944/fine-art-prints.htm?ui=76947CF94DBD4E59981ADAA5E7C14F65 this page , mouseover any image and click on of the directions.You will see another popup with image on left hand side and grid images on the right hand side.When you click on of the image on the grid and click arrow again , the left image gets updated. Our business wants to have a transition effect and i never did that so I asked here to provide a LOE in my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Images cannot *actually* fade into other images; you need to fake it.

Have one of the images floating the other using CSS. One should be hidden, and one should be visible. When you want to switch between the two, fade the hidden one in to be visible as you fade the visible one out to be hidden.

This [Image Cross Fade Transition](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-cross-fade-transition/) article discusses different methods of how to do this with jQuery :)

Comment: do you know any websites doing this? I want to see how they are doing with jquery.

Comment: @gov: just put in a neat little blog link :)