# windows scroll smooth effect

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which centers the popup when we scroll , it quickly re-positions itselef to center. How to get the smoothing effect as if it is dropping very smooth.

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {

        var top = ($(window).height() - $('.myPopUp').height()) / 2 + $(window).scrollTop();
        $('.myPopUp').animate({ top: top }, 10);

});
```

I tried to play around with speed , but its pretty fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to increase your animation duration, currently at 10ms, like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var top = ($(window).height() - $('.myPopUp').height()) / 2 + $(window).scrollTop();
  $('.myPopUp').animate({ top: top }, 200);
});
```

Animation frames are on a 13ms interval, so 10ms will be an instant change, giving it a longer duration, like the 200ms above will give it a much smoother effect.  For quick scrolling scenarios, you'll probably want a [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) in there too, like this:

```
$('.myPopUp').stop(true).animate({ top: top }, 200);
```

Comment: you are brilliant thank you very much , that stop and increasing the time gives a smooth effect.Once again thank you

Comment: any idea about this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006674/jquery-image-animation-from-one-location-to-another, it will great if you can provide some direction. I got some answer but i tried wit all variations but it didn't come the way i wanted