# AJAX form submission when enter is used to submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a designer insisting on a single form field submitted by hitting enter and the post made by AJAX and the response presented by Fancybox.

Problem is the the `return false` is not preventing the submission of the page.

What am I doing wrong there?

```
<form id="home_stay_informed_form">
<input name="informed_email" id="home_informed_email" value="Enter your email address..." />
</form>


$('#home_stay_informed_form').submit(function() {
  var reg = new RegExp(/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/);
  var em = $("#home_informed_email").val();
  if (!reg.test(em)) {
  alert('Please correct your email address.');
  $("#home_informed_email").focus();
    return false;
  } else {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'listSubscribe.php',
    data : 'email=' + em,
    success: function(msg) {
     $("#home_stay_informed_form_msg").fancybox({
    'titlePosition'  : 'outside',
    'transitionIn'  : 'none',
    'transitionOut'  : 'none'
   });
    $("#home_informed_email").val('Enter your email address...');
    return false;
    }
  });   
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `return false` needs to do in the `submit` handler directly, like this:

```
$('#home_stay_informed_form').submit(function() {
  var reg = new RegExp(/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/);
  var em = $("#home_informed_email").val();
  if (!reg.test(em)) {
    alert('Please correct your email address.');
    $("#home_informed_email").focus();
  } else {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'listSubscribe.php',
      data : 'email=' + em,
      success: function(msg) {
        $("#home_stay_informed_form_msg").fancybox({
          'titlePosition'  : 'outside',
          'transitionIn'  : 'none',
          'transitionOut'  : 'none'
        });
        $("#home_informed_email").val('Enter your email address...');
      }
    });   
  }
  return false;
});
```

Your `success` handler doesn't run until the server response comes back, so your function is actually returning `undefined` for that `else` statement...and that `return false` inside doesn't have any effect.  Putting it in the `submit` handler directly like is it above will do what you want, preventing the form submit.

---

A bit cleaner would be [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/), by adding the event parameter here:

```
$('#home_stay_informed_form').submit(function(e) {
```

And replacing `return false` with

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: we can use ajax beforesend also to do validations right, is that valid in the above context.

Comment: @gov - yup, some validation frameworks support this...if doing it custom, just call the native `form.submit()` in your `success` handler...but still `return false` from the main `submit` handler.

Comment: have you ever done this type of things , i asked a question here but didn't get exact answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006674/jquery-image-animation-from-one-location-to-another

Comment: I want to know whether this can be achieved through jquery or not